# Отображение BottomNavigationView в NavigationComponent

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

В своем приложении использую Single Activity подход.
На рисунке изображена схема поведения навигации, которую я хочу достичь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева экран с табами и контентом должен показываться сразу при старте приложения.
В качестве контента выступает RecyclerView со списком элементов. Если нажать на
элемент, то мы должны попасть на другой экран (на рисунке справа).
При нажатии кнопок в BottomNavigationView мы должны попадать на другие связанные с
этими кнопками экраны (фрагменты).

Схема выглядит достаточно просто, но я не могу понять как мне настроить компонент
навигации, согласно этой схеме.
Предположим у меня в MainActivity хранится FragmentContainerView с графом навигации,
тогда как будет выглядеть второй экран? Туда тоже придется ложить уже другой
FragmentContainerView с графом навигации?

Comment: BottomNavigationView вставить в Активити, там где FragmentContainerView, и просто скрывать его в определенных фрагментах. Но при этом, если Вы будете использовать анимации переходов от одного фрагмента к другому, будете сталкиваться с неприятным дерганием контента. Не критично, но не приятно для глаза. Альтернатива - ViewPager2 + BottomNavigationView.